# Formatting output in Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have created a table in an Oracle database as shown below:

```
create table employee(eid int, enameemp varchar(1), emgrid int);

insert into employee values(101,'A',103);
insert into employee values(102,'B',103);
insert into employee values(103,'C',104);
insert into employee values(104,'D',101);
//Displaying the table contents

select * from employee;


   EID E     EMGRID
   --- -     ------
   101 A        103
   102 B        103
   103 C        104
   104 D        101
```

The column name is not displayed completely unlike MySQL. Is there any way I can go about it without increasing the column size of enameemp i.e enameemp varchar(10)?

Comment: It depends on your client software.  Use GUI tool (like Toad) instead of SQLPlus.

Comment: Actually I am a newbie to SQL and I am trying to learn the SQL commands, So no to any GUI tools.

Comment: What you are asking is NOT an SQL command.  It is setting of SQLPlus client (most unpleasant client imho).

Comment: Ha. I got It... Thank you Egor :), By the way I got What i needed from the below answer, by OracleUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `SQL*Plus`, By default the output column size would be colummn size itself. If you wish have a custom size you can always.

Try the below command.

```
COL COLUMN_NAME FORMAT A<ur column size>
```

**EXAMPLE**: `COL ENAMEEMP FORMAT A10`

More SQL plus options from  [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm)

Comment: When I do this am I changing the size of the column, or just only the size of column name..

Comment: It is purely the display, the table is untouched.

Comment: Thank you, Oracle User, Got it... :)